# LuaJava Unsatisfied Link Error

Tags: java, eclipse, lua, luajava

I have a super simple program. And whenever I try running it in Eclipse I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no luajava-1.1 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.keplerproject.luajava.LuaState.<clinit>(LuaState.java:92)
    at org.keplerproject.luajava.LuaStateFactory.newLuaState(LuaStateFactory.java:59)
    at com.gmail.developnickmaster21.LuaJavaTesting.ClassThatUsesLuaJava.main(ClassThatUsesLuaJava.java:9)
```

I'm not quite sure where to begin with that... I have double check that the LuaJava jar is where I say it is and it still won't work. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

It means that you did not setup Lua libs properly.
First of all add to your Main-class that code:

```
static {
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
}
```

I'm absolutely sure there's no path to your luajava-1.1.dll\so

So here's 3 solutions:

1)Go to VM config (Run -> Run Configuration -> Arguments ->) and add to "VM arguments" the following `-Djava.library.path="PATH_TO_YOUR_OWN/luajava-1.1;${env_var:PATH}"`

2)Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> User Libraries -> add library with your `luajava-1.1.jar` -> edit "Native library location" to path to your `luajava-1.1.dll`

3)Add folder with `luajava-1.1.dll` to your system variable PATH (or just move that lib to any folder already in PATH)

Comment: For 1) - note that the java.library.path should have the path of the folder containing the .dll, and not .dll itself (like a jar). Hope this helps.